# cocoa pods install on iOS project not working

Tags: ios, ruby, react-native, cocoapods

I have a react native project and want to install cocoa pods for iOS native specifics but the instal fails, I have ruby ruby 2.5.1p57 on Mac book pro

I have posted the error down, would be grateful for help

```
pod install


    Analyzing dependencies
Fetching podspec for `DoubleConversion` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec`
Fetching podspec for `Folly` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/Folly.podspec`
Fetching podspec for `GLog` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/GLog.podspec`
Fetching podspec for `React` from `../node_modules/react-native`
Fetching podspec for `react-native-fetch-blob` from `../node_modules/react-native-fetch-blob`
Fetching podspec for `react-native-google-maps` from `../node_modules/react-native-maps`
Fetching podspec for `react-native-maps` from `../node_modules/react-native-maps/`
Fetching podspec for `yoga` from `../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga`
Downloading dependencies
Using DoubleConversion (1.1.5)
Using Folly (2016.09.26.00)
Installing GLog (0.3.4)
#<Thread:0x00007fd5349ba008@/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods/executable.rb:166 run> terminated with exception (report_on_exception is true):
Traceback (most recent call last):
    3: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods/executable.rb:169:in `block in reader'
    2: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods/executable.rb:169:in `loop'
    1: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods/executable.rb:170:in `block (2 levels) in reader'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods/executable.rb:170:in `readpartial': stream closed in another thread (IOError)
#<Thread:0x00007fd5349b9ea0@/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods/executable.rb:166 run> terminated with exception (report_on_exception is true):
Traceback (most recent call last):
    3: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods/executable.rb:169:in `block in reader'
    2: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods/executable.rb:169:in `loop'
    1: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods/executable.rb:170:in `block (2 levels) in reader'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods/executable.rb:170:in `readpartial': stream closed in another thread (IOError)
[!] /bin/bash -c 
set -e
#!/bin/bash
set -e

PLATFORM_NAME="${PLATFORM_NAME:-iphoneos}"
CURRENT_ARCH="${CURRENT_ARCH:-armv7}"

export CC="$(xcrun -find -sdk $PLATFORM_NAME cc) -arch $CURRENT_ARCH -isysroot $(xcrun -sdk $PLATFORM_NAME --show-sdk-path)"
export CXX="$CC"

# Remove automake symlink if it exists
if [ -h "test-driver" ]; then
    rm test-driver
fi

./configure --host arm-apple-darwin

# Fix build for tvOS
cat << EOF >> src/config.h

/* Add in so we have Apple Target Conditionals */
#ifdef __APPLE__
#include <TargetConditionals.h>
#include <Availability.h>
#endif

/* Special configuration for AppleTVOS */
#if TARGET_OS_TV
#undef HAVE_SYSCALL_H
#undef HAVE_SYS_SYSCALL_H
#undef OS_MACOSX
#endif

/* Special configuration for ucontext */
#undef HAVE_UCONTEXT_H
#undef PC_FROM_UCONTEXT
#if defined(__x86_64__)
#define PC_FROM_UCONTEXT uc_mcontext->__ss.__rip
#elif defined(__i386__)
#define PC_FROM_UCONTEXT uc_mcontext->__ss.__eip
#endif
EOF

checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for arm-apple-darwin-strip... no
checking for strip... strip
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... ./install-sh -c -d
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... no
checking for nawk... no
checking for awk... awk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking for arm-apple-darwin-gcc... /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/cc -arch armv7 -isysroot 
checking whether the C compiler works... no
xcrun: error: SDK "iphoneos" cannot be located
xcrun: error: SDK "iphoneos" cannot be located
xcrun: error: SDK "iphoneos" cannot be located
xcrun: error: unable to lookup item 'Path' in SDK 'iphoneos'
/Users/simoncigoj/Library/Caches/CocoaPods/Pods/External/GLog/f09d6cdb8398b4922e87d51f5245de7e-ed471/missing: Unknown `--is-lightweight' option
Try `/Users/simoncigoj/Library/Caches/CocoaPods/Pods/External/GLog/f09d6cdb8398b4922e87d51f5245de7e-ed471/missing --help' for more information
configure: WARNING: 'missing' script is too old or missing
configure: error: in `/Users/simoncigoj/Library/Caches/CocoaPods/Pods/External/GLog/f09d6cdb8398b4922e87d51f5245de7e-ed471':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
```

Comment: Did you install/updated XCode? Check this: https://github.com/gomatcha/matcha/issues/6

Comment: Yes I have a fresh install of xcode

Comment: @Larme please give an actual answer with this link and I will accept it it was the right answer and it helped ... tnx

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Looking at the error logs:

```
checking for arm-apple-darwin-gcc... /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/cc -arch armv7 -isysroot 
checking whether the C compiler works... no
xcrun: error: SDK "iphoneos" cannot be located
xcrun: error: SDK "iphoneos" cannot be located
xcrun: error: SDK "iphoneos" cannot be located
xcrun: error: unable to lookup item 'Path' in SDK 'iphoneos'
```

There is the same kind of error on [this link](https://github.com/gomatcha/matcha/issues/6).

You either need to do a `xcode-select`, or at least in XCode, `Preferences/Locations/Command Line Tools`, I guess.

Comment: You have to select the version of the Command Line Tools inside the Xcode after installing them from your Terminal app.

Answer (score 148):

Just execute the below command and you should be good to go:

`sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app`

[Credits](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/18408#issuecomment-386696744)

Comment: This fixed the issue for me, thanks! 
Could you explain how it works?

Comment: resetting the path also seems to work: `sudo xcode-select -r`

Comment: Thanks, @TayyabMazhar path resetting worked for me!

Comment: The example name of Xcode.app may change.
As @Larme mentioned in the answer above, the exact name can be found from XCode preferences. If you go to Preferences in XCode and then Locations, then Command Line Tools, here you will see the exact name and location of your current XCode app

Comment: Worked for me as well

Comment: works for  me as well

Answer (score 15):

**Command** sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app

**Response**
xcode-select: error: invalid developer directory '/Applications/Xcode.app'

**Command** xcrun --sdk iphoneos --show-sdk-path

**Response**
xcrun: error: SDK "iphoneos" cannot be located
xcrun: error: SDK "iphoneos" cannot be located
xcrun: error: unable to lookup item 'Path' in SDK 'iphoneos'

**Command** to get Xcode path Xcode-select --print-path

**Response**

/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools

**To Fix this**

XCode->Preferences->Locations->Command Line Tools  and select the xcode

This worked for me

Comment: this worked for me.. fresh installed xcode 12.4

Comment: worked for me aswell

Answer (score 2):

In my case the XCode path contained a space:  `/Applications/Xcode\ 12.4.app`

Only after renaming the XCode version to `Xcode12.4.app` and then running `sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode12.4.app` solved the issue.