# Issue with "pod install"

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, mobile-development

I have install cocoa pod using "sudo gem install cocoapods" command.

cocoapods installation seems fine.

Then I ran "pod install" command and below is the output on my terminal.

```
Muqiturs-MBP:ios muqiturrehman$ pod install
Adding a custom script phase for Pod RNFBApp: [RNFB] Core Configuration
Detected React Native module pods for RNCAsyncStorage, RNCMaskedView, RNFBApp, RNGestureHandler, RNReanimated, RNSVG, RNScreens, RNVectorIcons, react-native-camera, react-native-checkbox, react-native-document-picker, react-native-notifications, react-native-safe-area-context, and react-native-splash-screen
Analyzing dependencies
Fetching podspec for `DoubleConversion` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec`
Fetching podspec for `Folly` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/Folly.podspec`
Fetching podspec for `glog` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec`
Downloading dependencies
Installing DoubleConversion (1.1.6)
Installing FBLazyVector (0.61.5)
Installing FBReactNativeSpec (0.61.5)
Installing Firebase (6.25.0)
Installing FirebaseAnalytics (6.5.1)
Installing FirebaseAnalyticsInterop (1.5.0)
Installing FirebaseCore (6.7.1)
Installing FirebaseCoreDiagnostics (1.5.0)
Installing FirebaseCoreDiagnosticsInterop (1.2.0)
Installing FirebaseInstallations (1.3.0)
Installing FirebaseInstanceID (4.3.4)
Installing FirebaseMessaging (4.4.1)
Installing Folly (2018.10.22.00)
Installing GoogleAppMeasurement (6.5.1)
Installing GoogleDataTransport (7.0.0)
Installing GoogleUtilities (6.7.0)
Installing PromisesObjC (1.2.9)
Installing Protobuf (3.12.0)
Installing RCTRequired (0.61.5)
Installing RCTTypeSafety (0.61.5)
Installing RNCAsyncStorage (1.8.1)
Installing RNCMaskedView (0.1.7)
Installing RNFBApp (7.2.1)
Installing RNFBMessaging (7.1.6)
Installing RNGestureHandler (1.6.0)
Installing RNReanimated (1.7.0)
Installing RNSVG (12.1.0)
Installing RNScreens (2.3.0)
Installing RNVectorIcons (6.6.0)
Installing React (0.61.5)
Installing React-Core (0.61.5)
Installing React-CoreModules (0.61.5)
Installing React-RCTActionSheet (0.61.5)
Installing React-RCTAnimation (0.61.5)
Installing React-RCTBlob (0.61.5)
Installing React-RCTImage (0.61.5)
Installing React-RCTLinking (0.61.5)
Installing React-RCTNetwork (0.61.5)
Installing React-RCTSettings (0.61.5)
Installing React-RCTText (0.61.5)
Installing React-RCTVibration (0.61.5)
Installing React-cxxreact (0.61.5)
Installing React-jsi (0.61.5)
Installing React-jsiexecutor (0.61.5)
Installing React-jsinspector (0.61.5)
Installing ReactCommon (0.61.5)
Installing Yoga (1.14.0)
Installing boost-for-react-native (1.63.0)
```

Till above its seems fine but probably "Installing glog (0.3.5)" is a problem. and below are those lines.

```
Installing glog (0.3.5)
[!] /bin/bash -c 
set -e
#!/bin/bash
# Copyright (c) Facebook, Inc. and its affiliates.
#
# This source code is licensed under the MIT license found in the
# LICENSE file in the root directory of this source tree.

set -e

PLATFORM_NAME="${PLATFORM_NAME:-iphoneos}"
CURRENT_ARCH="${CURRENT_ARCH}"

if [ -z "$CURRENT_ARCH" ] || [ "$CURRENT_ARCH" == "undefined_arch" ]; then
    # Xcode 10 beta sets CURRENT_ARCH to "undefined_arch", this leads to incorrect linker arg.
    # it's better to rely on platform name as fallback because architecture differs between simulator and device

    if [[ "$PLATFORM_NAME" == *"simulator"* ]]; then
        CURRENT_ARCH="x86_64"
    else
        CURRENT_ARCH="armv7"
    fi
fi

export CC="$(xcrun -find -sdk $PLATFORM_NAME cc) -arch $CURRENT_ARCH -isysroot $(xcrun -sdk $PLATFORM_NAME --show-sdk-path)"
export CXX="$CC"

# Remove automake symlink if it exists
if [ -h "test-driver" ]; then
    rm test-driver
fi

./configure --host arm-apple-darwin

# Fix build for tvOS
cat << EOF >> src/config.h

/* Add in so we have Apple Target Conditionals */
#ifdef __APPLE__
#include <TargetConditionals.h>
#include <Availability.h>
#endif

/* Special configuration for AppleTVOS */
#if TARGET_OS_TV
#undef HAVE_SYSCALL_H
#undef HAVE_SYS_SYSCALL_H
#undef OS_MACOSX
#endif

/* Special configuration for ucontext */
#undef HAVE_UCONTEXT_H
#undef PC_FROM_UCONTEXT
#if defined(__x86_64__)
#define PC_FROM_UCONTEXT uc_mcontext->__ss.__rip
#elif defined(__i386__)
#define PC_FROM_UCONTEXT uc_mcontext->__ss.__eip
#endif
EOF

# Prepare exported header include
EXPORTED_INCLUDE_DIR="exported/glog"
mkdir -p exported/glog
cp -f src/glog/log_severity.h "$EXPORTED_INCLUDE_DIR/"
cp -f src/glog/logging.h "$EXPORTED_INCLUDE_DIR/"
cp -f src/glog/raw_logging.h "$EXPORTED_INCLUDE_DIR/"
cp -f src/glog/stl_logging.h "$EXPORTED_INCLUDE_DIR/"
cp -f src/glog/vlog_is_on.h "$EXPORTED_INCLUDE_DIR/"

checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for arm-apple-darwin-strip... no
checking for strip... strip
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... ./install-sh -c -d
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... no
checking for nawk... no
checking for awk... awk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking for arm-apple-darwin-gcc... /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/cc -arch armv7 -isysroot 
checking whether the C compiler works... no
xcrun: error: SDK "iphoneos" cannot be located
xcrun: error: SDK "iphoneos" cannot be located
xcrun: error: SDK "iphoneos" cannot be located
xcrun: error: unable to lookup item 'Path' in SDK 'iphoneos'
/Users/muqiturrehman/Library/Caches/CocoaPods/Pods/External/glog/2263bd123499e5b93b5efe24871be317-1f3da/missing: Unknown `--is-lightweight' option
Try `/Users/muqiturrehman/Library/Caches/CocoaPods/Pods/External/glog/2263bd123499e5b93b5efe24871be317-1f3da/missing --help' for more information
configure: WARNING: 'missing' script is too old or missing
configure: error: in `/Users/muqiturrehman/Library/Caches/CocoaPods/Pods/External/glog/2263bd123499e5b93b5efe24871be317-1f3da':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
```

Not very sure what is the issue here

Please help me solve this.

Comment: Does it answer your question? [how to fix configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables](https://askubuntu.com/q/647583/1009206)

Comment: no it does not solve my problem.

Comment: I found answer here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51768515/cocoa-pods-install-on-ios-project-not-working

Answer (score 2):

probably you can try this:

```
arch -x86_64 pod install
```

Comment: Why would you expect this to resolve the issue?

Comment: I had this issue before, and that was the bug of cocoapods. I saw this solution in the github issues thread.